# Cannot copy files from docker to tmp of host using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

docker -v:
Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638

docker-compose.yml:
    version: "2"

```
services:
    test-docker:
        build: ./test-docker

        volumes:
            - /tmp:/tmp

        command: /bin/bash -c "mkdir -p /my && mkdir -p /tmp/my \
            && echo 'tmp:' && ls /tmp && echo 'code:' && ls /my \
            && cp -r /my/nLWjfTg9 /tmp/my/nLWjfTg9 \
            && cp -r /my/WzzrKGqe /tmp/my/WzzrKGqe"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04 ENV TERM xterm
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive   
ADD http://pastebin.com/raw/nLWjfTg9 /my
ADD http://pastebin.com/WzzrKGqe /my
```

docker-compose up:

test-docker_1  | mkdir: cannot create directory '/my': File exists

tmp on host not create.

Comment: the idea of docker is isolation, so you should never be able, from a docker container, to access the host. The host can copy whatever it wants to any docker container.

Comment: see `docker cp`for copy, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Answer (score 0):

The `ADD` instruction in your Dockerfile creates the `/my` directory in the image.

In your command you run `mkdir -p /my` - which already exists, so you get your error and the command ends before copying any files.